# "angular ng-animate" instead of "angular.element animate"

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

What is correct way to write the same, but with app.animation and ng-animate?

```
angular.element('.headerSearch').animate({ "padding-top": "-=120px", "margin-top": "-=30px" }, "slow" );
```

Comment: When do you want the animation to take place?

Comment: After clicking on some link.

Comment: Will the link change the active view or will it just make an element show?

Comment: It will change the active view.

Comment: So after the new view is loaded you want elements with the class headerSearch to animate automatically?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely right